# Reset macOS to factory settings

Tags: macos

Is there a way to reset macOS to factory settings (but without loss of my personal files, such as documents and music, in my Home directory)?

There is an article about how to reinstall macOS: https://support.apple.com/HT204904, but it seems it doesn't reset macOS settings to factory ones.

Comment: What do you mean with „reset to factory settings“? Is there a problem you are trying to solve by attempting to do so?

Comment: _"What do you mean with 'reset to factory settings'?"_ - For example, I may turn off "Use smart quotes and dashes" at some point, which is turned on by default. And after I reset macOS to factory settings, this option should be changed back from "off" to "on".

Comment: These are user-specific settings, stored in your home directory. Easiest way to reset them is to create a new user account, move your data over, and delete the old one.

Comment: Re "loss of your personal files"... you're making backups, aren't you?

Comment: @nohillside Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could delete all the plist files (including invisible ones) in user/Library/Preferences, for a start. There might be unforeseen consequences, though -- but a new user account would be similarly empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no. You must back up your personal files as the reset deletes everything and you would then hand migrate back just the documents and not the settings.

If you’re ready to erase everything, follow along the steps according to your hardware model and OS version.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212749

There’s no partial process that Apple delivers and I can’t imagine anyone coming up with a tool to effectively roll back some but not all user file changes. You could make a new user account and try to compare files in the libraries for both on the user side, but there are a lot of hurdles to implementing such a concept.

Hand moving just your documents to a new user account works great if you have enough space to do this (either by copying in to /Users/Shared or authenticating as admin and copying them directly). You’ll need an external drive or a backup copy if you run out of space so you can delete them from the old account then bring them back from off-device.

Comment: The OP wishes to keep their data.

Comment: Yikes - thanks for pointing that out. This reset is clearly a total erase @lhf

Comment: Mike, thanks, but what if I simple create a new user account and manually copy all my personal files there, as @nohillside suggested in the comments? Seems to be a reliable solution.

Comment: Yes - that is a very good way to get default state and your documents @jsx97

Comment: That will copy your documents, but not your settings, saved browser data, passwords, etc.