# Erase & reset user settings without losing my files

Tags: macos, time-machine, restore, recovery

I want to reset all the user settings that have changed on my MacBook, without losing any of my user files.

My issue: I've made a lot of changes to my system as a developer: user permissions, installing global npm & homebrew packages, swapping nodeJS, PHP & python versions repeatedly, crud built up from Java, Docker, VirtualBox, and other tools. I want to remove all of this with a fresh macOS installation, but without losing the files in my user directory.

I am looking at Apple's support docs, and they cover this as separate tasks:

- [What to do before you sell, give away, trade in or recycle your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201065)
- [How to reinstall macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204904)
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/102551

*First, is erasing my MacBook completely and then restoring user files from a Time Machine backup the best way to reset my user config?* Would something else work?

*Next, will this achieve the result I'm looking for?* Will there be user settings hidden in my Time Machine backup that persist after the reset? Will I need to delete things from my Library folder? Is there anything I might loose (ex, my .zshconf file) that should be backed up separately?

This MacBook is an old 15-inch Mid 2015 running 10.15 right now, and I want to upgrade the newest version of macOS Monterey.

Comment: Restoring from TM will restore all your settings and other customisation - not what you want.

Comment: See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/467941/22769